# Autodiff for Jacobian derivative with respect to individual joint angles

Tags: drake

I am trying to compute $\partial{J}{q_i}$ in drake C++ for manipulator and as per my search, the best approach seems to be using autodiff function. I was not able to fully understand autodiff approach from the resources that I found, so I apologize if my approach is not clear enough.  I have used my understanding from some already asked questions mentioned on the forum regarding auto diff as well as https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_multibody_plant.html as reference.

As I want to calculate  $\partial{J}{q_i}$, the return type will be a tensor i.e. 3 * 7 * 7(or  6 * 7 * 7 depending on the spatial jacobian). I can think of using std::vectorEigen::MatrixXd to allocate the output or alternatively just doing one $q_i$ at a time and computing the respective jacobian for the auto diff. In either case, I was struggling to pass it in the initializing the jacobian function.
I did the following to initialize autodiff

```
std::unique_ptr<multibody::MultibodyPlant<AutoDiffXd>> mplant_autodiff = systems::System<double>::ToAutoDiffXd(mplant);
std::unique_ptr<systems::Context<AutoDiffXd>> mContext_autodiff = mplant_autodiff->CreateDefaultContext();

mContext_autodiff->SetTimeStateAndParametersFrom(*mContext);
const multibody::Frame<AutoDiffXd>* mFrame_EE_autodiff = &mplant_autodiff->GetBodyByName(mEE_link).body_frame();
const multibody::Frame<AutoDiffXd>* mWorld_Frame_autodiff = &(mplant_autodiff->world_frame());

//Initialize the q as autodiff vector
drake::AutoDiffVecXd q_autodiff = drake::math::InitializeAutoDiff(mq_robot);
MatrixX<AutoDiffXd> mJacobian_autodiff; // Linear Jacobian matrix.

mplant_autodiff->SetPositions(context_autodiff.get(), q_autodiff);

mplant_autodiff->CalcJacobianTranslationalVelocity(*mContext_autodiff,
                                      multibody::JacobianWrtVariable::kQDot,
                                      *mFrame_EE_autodiff,
                                      Eigen::Vector3d::Zero(),
                                      *mWorld_Frame_autodiff,
                                      *mWorld_Frame_autodiff,
                                      &mJacobian_autodiff 
                                      );
```

However, as far as I understand, InitializeAutoDiff initializes to the identity matrix, whereas I want to  $\partial{J}{q_i}$, so is there is a better way to do it. In addition, I get error messages when I try to call the jacobian matrix. Is there a way to address this problem both for $\partial{J}{q_i}$ for each q_i and changing q_i in a for loop or directly getting the result in a tensor. My apologies if I am doing something total tangent to the correct approach. I thank you in anticipation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, as far as I understand, InitializeAutoDiff initializes to the identity matrix, whereas I want to $\partial{J}{q_i}$, so is there is a better way to do it

That is correct. When you call `InitializeAutoDiff` and compute `mJacobian_autodiff`, you get a matrix of AutoDiffXd. Each AutoDiffXd has a `value()` function that stores the double value, and a `derivatives()` storing the gradient as an Eigen::VectorXd. We have

```
mJacobian(i, j).value() = J(i, j)
mJacobian_autodiff(i, j).derivatives()(k) = ∂J(i, j)/∂q(k)
```

So if you want to create a `std::vecot<Eigen::MatrixXd>` such that the k'th entry of this vector stores the matrix ∂J/∂q(k), then here is a code

```cc
std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd> dJdq(q_autodiff.rows());
for (int i = 0; i < q_autodiff.rows(); ++i) {
  dJdq[i].resize(mJacobian_autodiff.rows(), mJacobian_autodiff.cols());
}
for (int i = 0; i < q_autodiff.rows(); ++i) {
  // dJidq stores the gradient of the ∂J.col(i)/∂q, namely dJidq(j, k) = ∂J(j, i)/∂q(k)
  auto dJidq = ExtractGradient(mJacobian_autodiff.col(i));
  for (int j = 0; j < static_cast<int>(dJdq.size()); ++j) {
    dJdq[j].col(i) = dJidq.col(j);
  }
}
```

**Compute ∂J/∂q(i) for a single i**

If you do not want to compute ∂J/∂q(i) for all i, but only for one specific i, you can change the initialization of q_autodiff from `InitializeAutoDiff` to this

```cc
AutoDiffVecXd q_autodiff(q.rows());
for (int k = 0; k < q_autodiff.rows(); ++k) {
  q_autodiff(k).value() = q(k)
  q_autodiff(k).derivatives() = Vector1d::Zero();
  if (k == i) {
    q_autodiff(k).derivatives()(0) = 1;
  }
}
```

namely q_autodiff stores the gradient ∂q/∂q(i), which is 0 for all k != i and 1 when k == i. And then you can compute mJacobian_autodiff using your current code. Now `mJacobian_autodiff(m, n).derivatives()` store the gradient of ∂J(m, m)/∂q(i) for that specific i. You can extract this gradient as

```cc
Eigen::Matrix dJdqi(mJacobian_autodiff.rows(), mJacobian_autodiff.cols());
for (int m = 0; m < dJdqi.rows(); ++m) {
  for (int n = 0; n < dJdqi.cols(); ++n) {
    dJdqi(m, n) = mJacobian_autodiff(m, n).derivatives()(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Hongkai. I appreciate your guidance, and it helped in understanding auto diff. However, I am still getting following error.


mJacobian_autodiff = drake::math::InitializeAutoDiff(mJv_robot1); //No error here if the line below is not called

mplant_autodiff->CalcJacobianTranslationalVelocity(parameters mentioned in code above)

I get the error first in InitAutoDiffXd() and then in :CalcJacobianTranslationalVelocity for autodiff. Can you please guide in that respect as well. The error can be found in  https://pastebin.com/Va0L8yvz

Comment: The issue is that when you call CalcJacobianTranslationalVelocity, one of the input argument is Eigen::Vector3d::Zero(), but the function expects an Eigen::Vector of AutoDiffXd. So you can use Eigen::Vector3d::Zero().cast<AutoDiffXd>() instead. This creates an Eigen::Vector of AutoDiffXd where each AutoDiffXd has empty gradient (hence will be used as a constant).

Comment: Thank you Hongkai. It solved the problem. I really appreciate the help and guidance.